# Singular or plural when referring to an event and a specific case of that event

Tags: verbs, grammatical-number

In sentences in which a verb references an event, and a particular case of that same event, should i use the singular or plural form for the verb?

for example:

"milk production, and in particular white milk production, **is/are** subject to severe scrutiny"

Comment: Tito: Welcome, and great question! Where have you looked, or asked, to find an answer? What did you discover? Add these to your posts and we can help give you a better answer.

Comment: i didn't really look anywhere yet, as posing this kind of questions to google is not trivial, and i thought stack exchange would be the perfect place for something like this. i'll keep you posted if i find anything!

Comment: Understood. Just making sure that (in the words of my boss) you "did some due diligence" before coming into the question; that's what makes a good question.

Comment: _.. and in particular white milk_ is equivalent to _especially white milk_; the conjunction _and_ merely leads to a subset of special interest. It does not result in a conjoined count noun phrase, and therefore doesn't need plural verb agreement.

Comment: John Lawler's explanation is correct, but if it's not clear in a specific instance, the trick I've always used to choose the correct plural usage is to  see which one is correct if the phrase surrounded by commas is omitted:

"Milk production is subject to severe scrutiny."  That's the part of the sentence to which your singular verb refers.

Am I off base with that?

Comment: is the choosing of a singular verb in this case generalisable to all statements containing parenthetical elements? another example would be "Production of non-coding RNAs, and in particular pervasive transcription, **is/are** phenomenon/a that led a life of relative obscurity."
also, @JohnLawler if you could add your answer i would be happy to accept it!

Comment: The choice has nothing to do with whether there's a parenthetical element. As @Liesmith said, you need to make the verb agree with the phrase without the parenthetical. If the main subject is singular, use _is_; if it's plural, use _are_.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase is saying that milk production (just one noun) **is** subject to severe scrutiny. The way in which the second noun is added is just adding emphasis to the first noun, like "all balls (especially bouncy ones) bounce" (please excuse the bad example here, I can't think of a better one at this time...